# creating strongly type custom html helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have created custom helper for the date of birth as follows.

> Custom Html Helper Method

```
public static MvcHtmlString DateOfBirthFor(this HtmlHelper html, string id ,int minYear, int maxYear, object htmlAttribute = null)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttribute);

        var days = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });
        var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });
        var years = Enumerable.Range(minYear, maxYear-(minYear-1)).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        });

        var mainDivTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        mainDivTag.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        mainDivTag.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        mainDivTag.InnerHtml = string.Concat(
            html.DropDownList("Day", days, new { style="width : 40px "}).ToHtmlString(),
            html.DropDownList("Month", months, new { style = "width : 40px " }).ToHtmlString(),
            html.DropDownList("Year", years, new { style = "width : 60px " }).ToHtmlString()
        );

        return new MvcHtmlString(mainDivTag.ToString());
    }
```

I have also written custom binder for the same control.

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "DateOfBirth")
        {
            DateTime dob = new   DateTime(int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Year"]), int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Month"]), int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Day"]));
            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, dob);
        }
```

}

But , now I have to make strongly custom helper for the same control. So, i don't have to write custom binding.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve that without a custom model binder. The reason for that is because in the custom helper you have written the dropdowns are bound with specific names (Day, Month and Year) and the default model binder is unable to bind those 3 values to a single DateTime instance.

Comment: If i remove the name and use id for each drop down then is it possible to bind them. If, yes the how?? If not please elaborate ur answer.

Comment: No, it is not possible. The id is not used for the binding. Only the `name` attribute of the input field. The reason for that is because when an HTML form is submitted the browser uses the names of the input fields in order to prepare the POST request that will be sent to the server. So basically the POST body payload will contain the following: `Day=08&Month=04&Year=2013`. Now you need a custom model binder to extract those values and pack them into a single DateTime instance. The default model binder would expect the POST payload to look like this: `SomeDateTimePropertyName=2013-04-08`.

Comment: is there any other way for achieving two way binding.(Meaning if i change in model the ui gets effected and vice versa)

Comment: The custom helper and model binder is the way to go in this case.

Comment: If i use custom helper and model binder then how to populate drop down when value is coming from database.

Comment: can i us ko binding for the above problem??

Comment: You should set the value of your view model property in the controller action. The helper will take care of populating the dropdowns.